# Rails content_tag method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I was browsing the source code of [this gem](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags/blob/master/lib/meta_tags/content_tag.rb) and I found a use of content_tag that confuses me a lot.

```
def render(view)
  view.content_tag(name, attributes[:content], attributes.except(:content))
end
```

I do not understand why content_tag is called on view. I generally use it as helper to generate HTML tags, but I've never called it as a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most commonly, `content_tag` is called in the context of a view - so, you don't need to call `view.content_tag` because the view knows how to respond to `content_tag` (and simply calling `content_tag` is the same as calling `self.content_tag`).

The `render` method that you're showing exists within the class `MetaTag` which inherits from `Tag`. `Tag` is a plain old Ruby object (PORO), so it doesn't know how to respond to `content_tag`.

But, as you can see, the `render` method takes a view as an argument. And, naturally, the `view` object knows how to respond to `content_tag`. So, calling `view.content_tag` is the way that `MetaTag` is able to render the content tag.

This is pretty much an instance of the Presenter Pattern (different people use different terms). Ryan Bates has a good RailsCast on this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U).

To your question in the comments, Rails doesn't "know" that `view` is an instance of `ActionView::Base`. You have the responsiblity of passing in an actual view instance. I tend to pass in the controller so that I have access to the view and params. Maybe something like this:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def foo_action
    FooPresenter.present(self)
  end

end
```

and...

```
class FooPresenter
  class << self

    def present(controller)
      new(controller).present
    end

  end # class methods

  #===================================================================
  # instance methods
  #===================================================================

    def initialize(controller)
      @controller = controller
    end

    def present
      content_tag :div, data: {foo: params[:foo]}, class: 'bar'
    end

  private

    def controller()  @controller                end
    def view()        controller.view_context    end
    def params()      controller.params          end

    def method_missing(*args, &block)
      view.send(*args, &block)
    end

end
```

By including the `method_missing` method, I no longer have to call `view.content_tag`. I can just call `content_tag`. FooPresenter won't find the method, so will send the call onto the `view` where the method will be found and executed.

Again, Ryan does a great job explaining all of this.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and for pointing me to that RailsCast. I still do not understand one thing: how do Rails know that `view` is an `ActionView::Base` view instance of a Rails view?

Comment: Your updated answer is great, but can you pls point me to the exact line in the linked source code (of the gem) where the ActionView::Base instance is actually passed to the method?

Comment: Wow! You're really making me work for this one... (kidding). So, on closer inspection of the referenced gem, the documentation offers **Using MetaTags in controller** and **Using MetaTags in view** - which indicates that this doesn't follow the PORO presenter pattern (sorry about that). Instead, the MetaTag methods are included in both `ActionController::Base` and `ActionView::Base` via the include methods called on lines 36 and 37 of `meta-tags/lib/meta_tags.rb`. In these contexts, `view` is always available.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too much details, `content_tag` is a method in the `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper` class. I believe this class' object is either automatically included in Rails views or the Rails view object delegates to this object.

This particular gem takes an `ActionView::Base` object as a parameter for its `render` method so that the method has access to `content_tag` method, which is part of `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper`. This is a decent example of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which is a fundamental principle of object oriented programming.